# What it is the most appropriate Stack Exchange site to ask about ontologies and knowledge bases?

Tags: support

I am interested in *ontologies* and *knowledge management*, but I cannot find the ideal place for those questions. Sometimes, I think that the best site for that is *Data Science*, and sometimes - *Computational Science* or *Computer Science*.

**What would be the most appropriate site for the above-mentioned types of questions?**

Comment: To Sean's point, maybe you could edit your question to add an example of one or two questions you want to ask. It'll help the community give _you_ better help.

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking which StackExchange is most appropriate? Data Science seems OK to me, but I am not sure it's clear what you are intending to ask about.

Answer (score -1):

In my view, that potentially falls under the domain of datascience.stackexchange. Text-mining and other data science-related tools frequently leverage ontologies, so I think it depends on whether your ontology question is data science in nature.